# Project Run Issue in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I start to run Meteor project in command prompt as shown below

```
C:\Users\dsk>e:

E:\>cd abc/red

E:\abc/red>meteor //Here I got the below error then click any button the error popup and close the error popup and doesn't runmeteor project

E:\abc/red>  //here some times get this (or) some time gets another

     (or)

 Exited with code: -1073741819
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

[image]

So please see the error and suggest me what to do?

Comment: What version of meteor are you using, and what operating system are you using? (presumably Vista or Win7?)

Answer (score 0):

Meteor isn't fully & officially supported on windows.

You could file an issue with the unofficial Windows Meteor project: https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor

Or you could use a virtual machine or vagrant to use the official Meteor under ubuntu, see https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5855677